# Clear Two Dimensional Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How can I clear a 6x6 "table", so that anything in it is cleared?
    (I made the clearbutton already with ActionListener...etc)

```
        //other code above that creates window, below is the code that creates the table I need to clear

         square = new JTextField[s][s];
    for (int r=0; r!=s; r++) {
        symbols[r] = new JTextField();
        symbols[r].setBounds(35+r*35, 40, 30, 25);
        win.add(symbols[r], 0);
        for (int c=0; c!=s; c++) {
            square[r][c] = new JTextField();
            square[r][c].setBounds(15+c*35, 110+r*30, 30, 25);
            win.add(square[r][c], 0);
        }
    }
    win.repaint();
}
```

Comment: What do you want? Set them to null? If so, just set them to null in a double for loop. Array[i][j] = null;

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664026/default-or-initial-value-for-a-java-enum-array

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the array and and set each element to null. You can use the [java.utils.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class to make things cleaner/neater.

```
for( int i = 0; i < square.length; i++ )
   Arrays.fill( square[i], null );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one line solution:

```
Arrays.stream(square).forEach(x -> Arrays.fill(x, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
for (int index = 0; index < square.length; index++) {
    square[index] = null;
}
square = null;
```

Will do more then the trick (in fact the last line would normally be enough)...

If you're really paranoid...

```
for (int index = 0; index < square.length; index++) {
    for (int inner = 0; inner < square[index].length; inner++) {
        square[index][inner] = null;
    }
    square[index] = null;
}
square = null;
```